# Would this question about copying Visual Studio to a drive backup be on topic?

Tags: support, specific-question, scope

I made a clone backup for my C: drive on the same disk and I forgot that Visual Studio 2022 is not yet installed as I did a factory reset recently due to system files corruption.

If I installed Visual Studio on the primary C: drive, how do I copy it over to the backup partition such that if one day I moved the data from the backup partition to the primary partition, instead of doing factory reset, Visual Studio would be available for use?

Is this question on topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not sure I actually follow what you're asking. The question appears to be about backups of files or an application though; that isn't programming related.

Comment: @ThomA It's about the IDE/Compiler

Comment: *Is* it though..? What about Visual Studio are you asking? How does a factory reset (of a PC?), I assume this means reinstallation of an OS, relate to a question about Visual Studio *specifically*?

Comment: This isn't directly related to coding but more about general application handling on drives. You could ask it, but my guess is that it would likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: It might be on-topic on [su] (read their tour first).

Comment: I kind of wonder if you even want such tools to be in the backup to be honest. For one as you experience, they dig themselves deep into the OS. Secondly, you tend to want to update them when a new version comes out. It be less effort to just install it fresh after putting back a backup. But that's largely opinionated.

Comment: @Gimby I always ignore the update pop-up in visual studio :)

Comment: While you could copy the Visual Studio’s installation folder, doing so, won’t be enough to run Visual Studio.  Visual Studio must be installed. Easier solution is creating an offline installation file for it. In my personal opinion this question would it be well received on SU.

Comment: *"I always ignore the update pop-up in visual studio"* Maybe this is the root of why you need to reinstall the OS; you aren't installing updates.

Comment: @ThomA I do update windows just not visual studio.

Comment: If I replaced "Visual Studio" in your question with any other program, or indeed any other file, and someone answered the resulting question, **why would that answer not be helpful to you**? If it would be helpful, then the question is clearly **not about** Visual Studio, but instead purely about backing up files. That is ordinary use of a computer, not a programming task.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's a general computing question that happens to involve an IDE.

In essence, you're asking how backup partitions work, which isn't a programming question in and of itself. That's off-topic on SO.

It *might* be on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), but as [Thom A mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425573/would-this-question-be-on-topic#comment965615_425573), make sure to check their [help pages](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: ...unless there are Visual Studio–specific elements to it that wouldn't apply to other programs (e.g., "I tried [standard way of doing this] but it reports '[MS-12345] Failed to find fooBar'.")